# After migration to sharepoint 2010 search result error Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'SPNavigation'

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am migrating MOSS 2007 portal to sahrepoint 2010. I am not doing visual uplgrade. to check search setting i typed a keyword and pressed enter anfd it threw me below error. please let me know what to do as I am completely new in this.

Do I need to add the "SPNavigaation" placeholder in my master page. I dont know what custom.master page it is refering.

**Error**:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'SPNavigation' in the master page '~masterurl/custom.master', verify content control's ContentPlaceHolderID attribute in the content page. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Cannot find ContentPlaceHolder 'SPNavigation' in the master page '~masterurl/custom.master', verify content control's ContentPlaceHolderID attribute in the content page.

Comment: Its master-page was created by the 2007? Maybe you will have to create a new master page-by 2010 and migrate all your content

Comment: Dear all I solved the issue by adding  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SPNavigation" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
in my master page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear all I solved the issue by adding "

`<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="SPNavigation" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`

"in my master page